# warping images and problem with the matrix of Homography opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem when I'm getting the results of using the function cvFindHomograhpy().

The results it gives negative coordinates, I will explain now what I'm doing.

I'm working on video stabilization by using optical flow method. I have estimated the location of the features in the first and second frame. Now, my aim is to warp the images in order to stabilize the images. Before this step I should calculate the homography matrix between the frames which I used the function mentioned above but the problem that I'm getting this results which it doesn't seem to be realistic because it has negative values and these values can be changed to more weird results.

```
0.482982            53.5034         -0.100254              
-0.000865877        63.6554         -0.000213824 
-0.0901095            0.301558        1
```

After obtaining these results I get a problem to apply for image Warping by using CvWarpPerspective(). The error shows that there is a problem with using the matrices. Incorrect transforming from "cvarrTomat"?

So where is the problem? Can you give me another suggestion if it's available?

Notice: if you can help me about implementing the warping in c++ it would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

A poor homography estimation can generate warping error inside CvWarpPerspective().
The homography values you have posted show that you have a full projective transformation that move points at infinity to points in 2d euclidean plane and it could be wrong.
In video stabilization to compute a good homography model usually other features are used such as harris corner, hessian affine or SIFT/SURF combined with a robust model estimator such as RANSAC or LMEDS.

Check out [this link](http://areshmatlab.blogspot.com/2010/04/video-stabilization.html) for a matlab example on video stabilization...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have waited a lot, anyway shi and Tomasi features are not acceptable?

Comment: You can use Shi and Tomasi features (cvGoodFeaturesToTrack function find corners using their approach by default) and there are a lot of papers that show your approach, for example (http://www.scss.tcd.ie/Kenneth.Dawson-Howe/Projects/FYP2004_MarkMcDonnell.pdf). However you can also extract sift features and find matching pairs using second nearest neighobur distance ratio, in my experience it works better to estimate an accurate homography

Comment: Another important thing to notice is the number of features you extract from your video frames!!! You should at least have 10 or more matching pairs to have a robust estimation